# jQuery .show won't work. Wrong selector?

Tags: jquery, html

**EDIT: solved: IDs can't start with a digit.**

---

[Here's what's it about -->](http://kerstlichtshow.hostingsiteforfree.com/updates%20tabs.php)

I made a div with tabs above it (2009 - 2013). In the div where the content should show up, I wrote just the year to indicate if my code works.

If I write `$('div#updates div.content div').hide();`, all the content hides (just as it should), but if I write `$('div#updates div.content div#2009').show();`, nothing happens. Does anyone know why (I supposed wrong selector, but I checked that and it didn't work.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="updates">
<div class="tabs">
    <div id="2009">2009</div>
    <div id="2010">2010</div>
    <div id="2011">2011</div>
    <div id="2012">2012</div>
    <div id="2013">2013</div>
</div><br />
<div class="content">
    <div id="2009">
        2009
    </div>
    <div id="2010">
        2010
    </div>
    <div id="2011">
        2011
    </div>
    <div id="2012">
        2012
    </div>
    <div id="2013" class="active">
        2013
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS (jQuery):**

```
        $(document).ready(function(e) {
            $('div#updates div.tabs div#2013').addClass("active");

            $('div#updates div.tabs div').click(function(e) {
                $('div#updates div.tabs div').removeClass("active");
                $(this).addClass("active");
                $('div#updates div.content div').hide();
            });

            $('div#updates div.tabs div#2009').click(function(e) {
                $('div#updates div.content div#2009').show();
            });
            $('div#updates div.tabs div#2010').click(function(e) {
                $('div#updates div.content div#2010').show();
            });
            $('div#updates div.tabs div#2011').click(function(e) {
                $('div#updates div.content div#2011').show();
            });
            $('div#updates div.tabs div#2012').click(function(e) {
                $('div#updates div.content div#2012').show();
            });
            $('div#updates div.tabs div#2013').click(function(e) {
                $('div#updates div.content div#2013').show();
            });
    });
```

**css:**

```
        div#updates div.tabs div{
        float: left;
        padding: 5px 10px 4px 10px;
        background-color: #a90000;
        border: 1px solid #600;
        z-index: inherit;
        position: relative;
        margin-right: -1px;
        cursor: default;
    }
    div#updates div.tabs div.active{
        background-color: #f00;
        border-bottom: none;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        z-index: 10;
    }
    div#updates div.content{
        background-color: #f00;
        position: absolute;
        top: 38px;
        width:500px;
        border: 1px solid #600;
        padding: 10px;
        z-index: 9;
    }
    div#updates div.content div{
        display: none;
    }
    div#updates div.content div.active{
        display: block;
    }
    /*opmaak berichten*/
    div#updates div.content div h3{
        color: #0f0;
        font: 24px Impact , sans-serif;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

Comment: Possibly you have duplicate id to div. In tabs and content children div have same id? Actually id should be unique in DOM

Comment: no, it was the id: they can't start with a digit, but thanx for your response anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your selectors are invalid. Even though `id` values starting with a digit are [valid in HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute), they are [**not** valid in CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier). Put an `x` in front of them or something to make them valid, e.g.

```
<div id="1">...</div>
```

becomes

```
<div id="x1">...</div>
```

so the selector `#x1` can be used (which is valid).

Additionally, as [Arun points out in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17676083/157247), you have used the same `id` value on more than one element. That's also invalid. `id` means "identifier," and identifiers are unique (that's the whole point). The behavior of the selector engine when you have the same `id` value on more than one element is undefined (because it's invalid), but usually the browser uses the first element in the document with that `id`.

I think you may have wanted this:

```
<div id="updates">
<div class="tabs">
    <div data-id="year2009">2009</div>
    <div data-id="year2010">2010</div>
    <div data-id="year2011">2011</div>
    <div data-id="year2012">2012</div>
    <div data-id="year2013">2013</div>
</div><br />
<div class="content">
    <div id="year2009">
        2009
    </div>
    <div id="year2010">
        2010
    </div>
    <div id="year2011">
        2011
    </div>
    <div id="year2012">
        2012
    </div>
    <div id="year2013" class="active">
        2013
    </div>
</div>
```

With this:

```
$(".tabs").on("click", "> div", function() {
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $("#" + this.getAttribute("data-id")).addClass("active");
});
```

What I changed:

1. I removed the `id` values from the divs within `.tabs` and used `data-id` to indicate which div they should activate.
2. I made the `id` values valid.
3. I had the code respond to clicks on the `.tabs` element, but only if the click was on one of its `div` children (delegated handling).
4. Use the `data-id` attribute to make the relevant div active.

Comment: but the [spec for class](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#classes) does not say that, it just says `must have a value that is a set of [space-separated tokens](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/common-microsyntaxes.html#set-of-space-separated-tokens) representing the various classes that the element belongs to`. so if a class name is not used as a css selector then it should be fine right

Comment: so which of these two spec is valid in this case? :(

Comment: @ArunPJohny: It's another case of context, just like `id`. It's fine to use `id` values starting with digits in HTML as long as you're not trying to use them with CSS. Similarly, it's fine to use class names starting with digits in HTML...as long as you don't use them with CSS. :-) The CSS rules apply if you're going to apply styling to those `id`s or classes, or look up elements using CSS selectors via jQuery or `querySelector` or similar. The CSS spec is quite clear: *"In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors)...cannot start with a digit..."*

Comment: @ArunPJohny: I did wonder if maybe you could escape the `id` or selector with a backslash, because the spec goes on to say *"... Identifiers can also contain escaped characters...For instance, the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?" or "B\26 W\3F"."* But Chrome, at least, rejects `querySelector("#\\123")` and `querySelector(".\\456")`. :-)

Answer (score 2):

[according to the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2), IDs in HTML4 have to begin with a letter. Numeric IDs are ok in HTML5, but they still aren't in CSS. most likely that causes your problems.

[What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Comment: @Zenith: thanks for the hint, i edited my answer according to that.

Answer (score 0):

The id should not start with a number, that's correct. Only works in Internet Explorer.

Comment: indeed, I now use x2009 instead of 2009 and so on.

Comment: Excellent, may I also suggest a more descriptive id like div2009 or tab2009.

Comment: I don't know if I uploaded my newest version, but I now use t2009 (tab) and c2009 (content).

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify your JS like this (and you can get rid of ID's):

```
$(function(e) {
    $(".tabs div").click(function(){
        var _index = $(this).index();

        $(".tabs div").removeClass("active");
        $(".tabs div:eq("+_index+")").addClass("active");

        $(".content div").hide();
        $(".content div:eq("+_index+")").show();
    });
});
```

Comment: I woud like to, but since I'm not that far with learning JS, it would just make things to complicate, but thanx for your answer anyway. When I'm done programming the website I did this for, I'll have a better look at it.

Comment: and `$('.tabs div:eq(4)').addClass("active");` to initially set `active` class to the last tab.

Answer (score 0):

Hi when using they should be unique and then you can link to them directly without telling about the parents. Direct link to the ID is the fastest way.

The jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
        $('#a2013').addClass("active");
        $('#b2013').show();
        $('div#updates div.tabs div').click(function(e) {
            $('div#updates div.tabs div').removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $('div#updates div.content div').hide();
        });

        $('#a2009').click(function(e) {
            $('#b2009').show();
        });
        $('#a2010').click(function(e) {
            $('#b2010').show();
        });
        $('#a2011').click(function(e) {
            $('#b2011').show();
        });
        $('#a2012').click(function(e) {
            $('#b2012').show();
        });
        $('#a2013').click(function(e) {
            $('#b2013').show();
        });
});
```

And the html:

```
  <div id="updates">
    <div class="tabs">
        <div id="a2009">2009</div>
        <div id="a2010">2010</div>
        <div id="a2011">2011</div>
        <div id="a2012">2012</div>
        <div id="a2013">2013</div>
    </div><br />
    <div class="content">
        <div id="b2009">
            2009
        </div>
        <div id="b2010">
            2010
        </div>
        <div id="b2011">
            2011
        </div>
        <div id="b2012">
            2012
        </div>
        <div id="b2013">
            2013
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I know, but this was an example which I have to put in a large website I'm working on later, so id might not be unique anymore, but thanx for your response.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem you have to follow 2 steps:

1. As my friend has said, you have to change the ID as it is invalid in CSS but valid in HTML5 (integer values for CSS simply does not work and jQuery uses CSS)
2. The purpose of IDs are to make it unique and identify it between all of the elements without typing the full path. You should use something like this

```
$('#x2009').show();
```

Comment: As soon as I finish the final website, I'll look for ids I could clean up. Thanx for your response.

Comment: @Jamil Please Do Not Use Capital Letters In The Middle Of Sentences Since It Reads Very Poorly!!! - I have fixed it for you